# ssrs 2008 : Do not want group header to appear for every group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pdf-generation, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I need to generate SSRS report as shown in the above picture (the top portion of the image got cut off but it has the header as shown below which should appear on only at top of each page).

HEADER is as below

Bin ItemNr  Description QtyOnHand

My data output is as below which I need to use to generate report format as shown above.

![enter image description here][2]

**Issues I am facing**

I used 2 tablix. The first tablix has groupby on ItemNr and I show only if the record has binPriority equal to 0. I then added another tablix within first tablix to findout if the itemNumber count is >1 (else I hide this tablix). Here I printed rows where binPriority is <> 0.

I get the data output somewhat similar to what I wanted but the header row appears for every item (where binPrority is 0).  I want it to appear only per page. So what I did was I set the row header within first tablix as invisible and added the textboxes within the page header. I guess this is not the way to do it but this is where I am so far).

Also when I export to PDF, I see blank lines between each item (See image below).  To me this lines looks like the 2nd tablix which is hidden. The report format/display is perfect when I view it on the screen.

The report is set to print in landscape and all the margins are 0.

Please suggest how to achieve the above report format.

Update 1 : I have modified the question by removing some of the images that had live data.

Comment: I wanted to edit this question as there are no responses but I decided to post it as another question. Here is the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945288/ssrs-report-facing-issues-with-master-detail-kind-of-report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am marking this question as answered. 
I modified the report by removing the 2nd tablix and using Grouping.